# Pre-execute a query when any Stored Procedure is called

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Our enterprise's database is 20+ years old, and it's filled with junk, so we're planning to start deleting tables and Stored Procedures. The problem is that we don't exactly know which of those are unused, so we thought on doing a research to spot them.

I tried [this answer's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7523), but I think the number of queries returned are the ones in the system cache.

I have an idea of how to do it, but I don't know if it's possible:
  - Create a system table with 3 columns: Stored Procedure name, number of executions, and date of last call
  - The tricky part: everytime a Stored Procedure is executed, perform a query to insert/update that table.

To avoid having to modify ALL our Stored Procedures (those are easily 600+), I thought of adding a Database Trigger, but turns out it's only possible to link them to tables, not Stored Procedures.

My question is, is there any way to pre-execute a query when ANY Stored Procedure is called?

EDIT: Our Database is a SQL Server

Comment: I doubt this is possible, but you should  tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You could use sql profiler to get a trace of all calls - and then post process the trace to parse out the information you need. Would be a larger trace though potentially.

Comment: This sounds like a job for extended events. Use a histogram target and capture `rpc_started` (or `rpc_completed`) events. Query this histogram and/or make a table of it at your leisure. If you need more details on what the calls are, make it an even file rather than a histogram.

Comment: @Andrew That's a good idea, but there are some Stored Procedures that are executed maybe once a month, so i was planning to count the number of calls in 1 or 2 months and then act accordingly.

Comment: @Jeroen Monstert I didn't know that thing existed, I'll definetely give it a try. I'll let you know if it worked. Many thanks :)

Comment: The only fly in the ointment is stored procedures that are called through `sp_executesql` -- a trace captures those, but (obviously) as calls to `sp_executesql`, not the sproc itself. You can use the command text field to distinguish, but a histogram can't count it effectively. Still, it's a low overhead way of doing the analysis. I just tried it on a production server and it easily counts 800 calls/sec with no noticeable overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that I asked this question a while ago, but I'll post what I've found, so anyone who stumbles with it can use it.

When the question was asked, my goal was to retrieve the number of times all Stored Procedures were executed, to try to get rid of the unused ones.

While this is not perfect, as it doesn't show the date of last execution, I found this query, which retrieves all Stored Procedures on all databases, and displays the number of times it's been executed since it's creation:

```
SELECT
    Db_name(st.dbid) [Base de Datos],
    Object_schema_name(st.objectid, dbid) [Schema],
    Object_name(st.objectid, dbid)        [USP],
    Max(cp.usecounts)                     [Total Ejecuciones]
FROM   
    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
    CROSS apply sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE  
    Db_name(st.dbid) IS NOT NULL
    AND cp.objtype = 'proc'
GROUP  BY
    cp.plan_handle,
    Db_name(st.dbid),
    Object_schema_name(objectid, st.dbid),
    Object_name(objectid, st.dbid)
ORDER  BY
        Max(cp.usecounts)
```

I found this script on [this webpage](https://sqlelemental.com/2013/01/13/monitorear-el-uso-de-procedimientos-almacenados/) (it's on spanish). It also has 2 more useful scripts about similar topics.

Answer (score 0):

I used this script (subsequently improved)

https://chocosmith.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/tsql-recompile-all-views-and-stored-proceedures-and-check-for-error/#more-571

To run through all of  your objects and find the ones that are no longer valid.

If you want I will post my enhanced version which fixes a few things.

Then create a new schema (I call mine `recycle`) and move those invalid objects in there.

Now run it again.

You may end up moving a whole bunch on non functional objects out

Comment: This finds procedures that can no longer execute in the first place, but it doesn't identify procedures that will still run, but are no longer used at all. You could find those by finding *tables* that are no longer used, dropping those and *then* running this script, but that might take quite a few tries -- and is dangerous to do on a production system.

Comment: You’re right it doesn’t answer the question as such but this is where I started when cleaning up another clients dB.